# "detail": "No active account found with the given credentials" simplejwt

Tags: django, jwt

I am using Django rest API and trying to authenticate a user with username and password (obtain token pairs) with simpleJWT. In my settings.py I have added

```
      REST_FRAMEWORK = {

     'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (

        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
    }
```

my urls.py is as below

```
     urlpatterns = [
          path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
          path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name ='token_obtain_pair'),
          path('api/token/refresh/', jwt_views.TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name ='token_refresh'),

        ]
```

However when I send a request to authenticate (register) a user and obtain token for that user it seems like it tries to verify the user instead and gives me the following error

```
     {
        "detail": "No active account found with the given credentials"
     }
```

I have read multiple other related questions but nothing helped. What should I do to obtain a token for an email address and password?

Comment: are you sure the given username and password are correct?

Comment: but isn't that for verifying a user to see if the user with those credentials exists? I want to register a new user and obtain token for it, the user is not registered before. If I use my superuser credentials it will give me a refresh token.

Comment: As the names suggest (`TokenObtainPairView`), it is the view to ***"obtain"*** the token, not a ***user registration URL/view***